# JNI function that composes jintArray from normal c int[]

Tags: java, interface, java-native-interface, native

I've been looking for a little bit now to figure out how to solve this problem, but nothing I've found quite answers this question correctly.  I think I'm close;  I'm going to want a jint* and an int*, as well as using the (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(...) function,

```
//  This function will take an array of global integers that already exist in the
//  c-side of the program, we'll call them 'data_ints[91]' (there are 91 just to clarify.)
/*...*/
int data_ints[] = {1,2,3,4,/*...*/90,91};

JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_MarsRoverGUI_getData
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint)
{
    jintArray out_ints;
    jint *outElements;
    int i;

    out_ints = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, 91);
    outElements = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env,out_ints,0);
    for (i = 0; i < 91; i++)
    {
        outElements[i] = data_ints[i];
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env,out_ints,outElements,0);

    // returns data_ints as a jintArray
    return out_ints;
}
```

Just how close am I?  I don't have an effective way of testing JNI /:  Feel free to suggest ways!

grazie all

Comment: That looks right but you are just going to have to find an effective way of testing it. You could always try compiling and linking it, and executing a test program.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well, this should work for you. You seem disturbed by the `int`/`jint` conversion, but you don't have to as `jint` is just a typedef for `int`.

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_MarsRoverGUI_getData
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint)
{
    jintArray out_ints;

    out_ints = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, 91);
    (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, out_ints, 0, 91, data_ints);

    // returns data_ints as a jintArray
    return out_ints;
}
```

Please tell me if anything seems unclear, or if I misunderstood your question!

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for clearing up the jint/int typedef sitch mbrenon!!